# Does Apache cache the gzipped version of a static file?

Tags: performance, apache, compression, gzip

If you configure Apache to enable gzip compression for your static HTML/CSS/JS/etc. files, it automatically outputs a gzipped version to any client that sends an appropriate `Accept-Encoding` request header. (And for other clients, it just sends the raw uncompressed file.)

My question is: does Apache recompress the raw file every time it is requested by a gzip-accepting client? Or does it cache the gzipped copy, and only recompress it if it notices the last-modified time on the file has changed?

And if it does cache a gzipped copy of your files, where is this cache stored?

Comment: Unless your server is struggling to serve requests, don't worry about it.

Comment: http://www.schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/cache.htm

Answer (score 4):

No it doesn't cache the gzipped file.

However the cost of compressing the file is less than the cost of squirting the extra packets across the network, hence even without caching you will see lower overall CPU usage (and lower memory usage, and fewer context switches) on your server - and a faster response at the client.

Note that the compressed file is **NOT** stored in the temp folder - mod_deflate reads input into a fixed size buffer in memory - and when the buffer is full (or the stream ends) the content is compressed and handed back to the webserver.

It will use even less CPU (although speed won't improve noticably) if the content is pre-compressed or cached serverside - there's multiple ways of doing this - mod_rewrite can test for the presence of filename.gz and serve it up in place of filename or you can use a reverse proxy (assuming the content is also served up with caching instructions).

Comment: There IS a tradeoff with mod_deflate, between CPU usage on the server and bandwidth savings - this article is old but demonstrates it pretty clearly: http://www.webperformance.com/library/reports/moddeflate/

Comment: NO IT IS NOT A TRADEOFF - as I tried to make clear in my answer, it takes fewer CPU cycles and context switches to compress the data than to process the transmission of the additional data. While interesting reading the article you linked is somewhat limited in its methodology and analysis.

Comment: How did you arrive at your conclusion that there's no tradeoff? This answer just states it to be true without any background information. You may be right but I imagine it varies based on particular hardware configuations etc. I'd be curious to see any links to performance testing results.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not. This is [described in the mod_deflate documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html#precompressed) now:

> Since mod_deflate re-compresses content each time a request is made, some performance benefit can be derived by pre-compressing the content and telling mod_deflate to serve them without re-compressing them.

Answer (score 0):

Apache does not keep any cached files. It only keeps the files you tell it to keep. Here is how compression works:

1. Browser requests page and states it accepts compression
2. Server finds page and reads the header of the request.
3. Server sends page to the browser (compresses if stated it accepts in header request - compressed file is stored in memory/temp folder)
4. Browser receives the information and displays (after decompression if compressed). The browser then caches the page and images.
5. Server removes any hint of the compressed file from memory/temp folder to free up space for the next request. It does log in the access_log the transaction.

The browser when it requests the same file or page again. It sends a request to the server stating that it accepts compression, and the current files and Modified Date. From here the server would respond that they are the same and send no additional information, or send only the changed files based on the Modified Date.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that info about it deleting the gzipped version straight after the request? It seems a bit crazy that it would keep repeatedly gzipping the same static files, once for every full request. I know `If-Modified-Since` requests would reduce the number of times this needs to happen, but it would still happen at least once per client, which is unnecessary if it's just serving static files.

Comment: The zipped version is stored in cache/memory. There used to be a way to do it with mod_gzip in Apache 1.3, pre-compression of files, and multiviews but have not looked it up since. I run multiple dedicated servers and have not seen any zipped versions actually stored on the server. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html shows how to change the memory limits

Comment: `mod_deflate` is the standard now and is more user-friendly. Plus with  pre-compressed files, you have to re-compress the files after an update or on a periodic basis to keep it up to date.

Comment: Neither mod_deflate nor mod_gzip use files.